# Using jquery, what is the best way to get the "next" textbox with a specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a bunch of repeating textboxes and comboboxes on an html page.  I want to change the value of the textbox below the combobox when i change the combobox.  So i have this code so far:

```
$('.myDropdown').change(function () {
    var currentDropdownValue = $(this).val(); 
    if (currentDropdownValue == "Regular") {
         //CHANGE TEXTBOX BELOW THIS COMBOBOX WITH CLASS = "QUANTITY" TO 10.
    }
});
```

here is my html

```
<select class="myDropdown">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input class="quantity" type="text" />
```

basically, i need to figure out the right selector syntax as i was using "Closest()" but that seems to only go up the DOM tree and not past the current value.

Comment: [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to return the next item or pass it a selector if you are more picky.

```
$(this).next('.quantity').val(10);
```

No need for extra DOM Traversing like parent() or such.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CXzVe/2/.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('.myDropdown').change(function () {
    var currentDropdownValue = $(this).val(); 
    if (currentDropdownValue == "Regular") {
         //CHANGE TEXTBOX BELOW THIS COMBOBOX WITH CLASS = "QUANTITY" TO 10.
        $(this).next('.quantity').val('10');
    }
});
```

You may need to jump around your HTML structure a bit if your input field isn't a sibling of your drop-down, such as `$(this).parent().next('.quantity').val('10')`.

Edit: here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KCZm/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be updating your DOM after the initial load of the page, you'll need to use `$.live()` or `$.delegate()` because jQuery is not aware of the change.

JavaScript

```
$(".manufacturer").live("change", function () {
    var currentValue = $(this).val(); 
    if (currentValue && currentValue === "Regular") {
         $(".quantity").val("10");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="manufacturer">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input class="quantity" type="text" />
```