# Best way to set focus on immediate next textbox on page

Tags: jquery

When I press enter on my current textbox I want to set my focus on the immediate next textbox where ever it would be onthe DOM.

I am not placing any code sample purposely because I dont have any specific scenario. My page loads through an ajax call and the DOM structure would not be known to me.

I am looking for a solution by making use of `type[text]` and not by using any `class` or `id` attribute.

I have been through [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155605/using-jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-next-textbox-with-a-specific-cla) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155605/using-jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-next-textbox-with-a-specific-cla) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543427/jquery-set-focus-on-first-textbox-on-pageload). I also, tried using below code sample:

```
$('body').on('keypress', 'input[type=text]', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) { // the enter key code
        debugger;
        $(this).closest('.ModalYearItem')
            .next().next().next()
            .find('.TargetMixPercent').focus();

        //  $(this).parents().nextAll('[type=text]').focus()   Approach 2
        //  $(this).parents().siblings()
        //      .find('[type=text]').next(':eq(0)').closest('type=text')    Approach 3
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of your HTML to the question so we can see how to traverse it.

Comment: Are you also using jQueryUI? That has some helpful extras that will make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index of the active focused input and simply move to the next input based on the next index.

Here is a long-hand version to make it obvious:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type=text]', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        var $el = $(this);
        var $inputs = $(':input');
        var indx = $inputs.index($el);
        $inputs.eq(indx + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mqnthf4n/2/

In `jQueryUI` you also have a `:focusable` selector (https://api.jqueryui.com/focusable-selector/) which will include everything that can be focused (including non-`input` elements!). Otherwise you need to cater for the various types yourself.

Note, this explanatory version does not handle wrapping around at the end, back to the first input, but you can add the range check yourself like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mqnthf4n/4/

**Note:**

- I changed `'body'` to `document` in the delegated event, as `body` has bugs (relating to styling) that can mean some events do not bubble to it. Always safer to use `document` (which is also a fraction faster as it does not need to be parsed). The overhead of one extra element in the bubble chain is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. One issue , that $inputs , this will get all the elements of the page which I didnt wanted, I modified this slightly as per my requirement. http://jsfiddle.net/6dpqd85w/

Comment: @Rohit Tiwari: Without sample HTML we can only guess your requirements from the code in the question :) Feel free to modify to restrict the range.

Answer (score 0):

See sample code See http://jsfiddle.net/xalvin11/typw6c8v/

```
$(':input').each(function (idx) {
    $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            var nextInput = $(':input').get(idx + 1);
            if (nextInput)
                nextInput.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One serious flaw in this version: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/typw6c8v/1/ You have assumed the inputs are all adjacent.

Comment: You have swapped a single delegated handler for separate handlers, just to have the index available in the key handler. That is very inefficient. Also if you use `eq` instead of `get` you do not need to test with `if (nextInput)`.